# A comment belongs to a user and belongs to a post. Can I still use the build method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

So say that I have a fairly typical blog.

```
A post belongs to a user.
A user has many posts.

A post has many comments.
A comment belongs to a post.
A comment belongs to a user.
```

I understand that when I'm creating a post I can do something like:

```
@post = @user.posts.build(subject: "Lorem ipsum", content: "Lorem ipsum") }
```

but I'm not sure how I'd do that for comments given that it's related to both a post and a user. For the sake of simplicity let's say comments just has three fields, content, user_id and post_id. Can I still use the build method somehow?  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: To your exact question, I'm not sure if you can still do it. An alternative method would be to just create the post, then the comment. `post = Post.create!(:user_id => @user.id, ...)` and then `Comment.create!(:content => "whatever", :user_id => @user.id, :post_id => post.id)`. The build would be nicer, but if you're banging your head, you can just create the objects manually.

Comment: A potential workaround solution that I've thought of is that I could eliminate the association with the user and have a commenter_name field or something. I could then find the current signed in user, grab the name attribute off of that then pass it to the build method. That way the user can't manipulate the name that appears next to the post. But it'd be good to know if this is possible.

Comment: One issue is that you're not guaranteed (unless you made a validation for it, which seems silly) that a user's name is unique. You could have 2 users named "Joe", or "Joe Brown", or "Joe Alfred Brown" - no guarantee.

Comment: That's very true, although I suppose you could include their email in brackets. For instance poster  = "#{current_user.name} (#{currentuser.email})" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@post.comments.build(...) do |c| 
  c.user = current_user 
end
```

I usually prefer to keep user_id as protected attribute.